# how to configure or write the regular expression for password field for following constraints?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, passwords

I want to implement sign up for where, I need regular expression for password field should accept only : `Alpha, Num, sp characters . - _ @ ! # $` . What i how to build regular expression for these. I am working in asp.net MVC.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why are you restricting the characters a user can enter into a password field?

Comment: yes I tried these : 1. @"^[a-zA-Z0-9._@!#$%&-]+$";              2.@"^([a-zA-Z0-9.*-_@!#$%&]+)$|\b";      3.@"((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-_@!#$%&\\.]).{6,20})"; but didn't worked

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9._@!#$%&-]+$` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this ^[a-zA-Z0-9._@!#$-]+$**